# map function in Scala clarification

Tags: scala

I am confused on how to write the map function, which maps over two lists:

for example:

```
def map[A,B,C](f: (A, B) => C, lst1: List[A], lst2: List[B]): List[C]
```

The input would be 2 lists and the output could be a list that adds the integers alternatively

Test example:

```
assert(map(add, List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6)) == List(5, 7, 9))
```

Comment: What if the lists are not the same size?

Comment: Can you explain with sample input and expected output?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the post

Answer (score 5):

You could use `f.tupled` to convert `f` from a function that accepts to arguments `(A, B) => C`, to a function that accepts one argument as a tuple `((A, B)) => C`. Then, you can `zip` the lists together (make them one list of tuples) and feed them to `f` using the traditional `map`.

```
def map[A,B,C](f: (A, B) => C, lst1: List[A], lst2: List[B]): List[C] = 
   (lst1 zip lst2) map f.tupled

scala> def add(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
add: (a: Int, b: Int)Int

scala> map(add, List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6))
res20: List[Int] = List(5, 7, 9)
```

Keep in mind that if the two lists are not the same size, then `zip` will truncate the longer list to match the size of the smaller one.

Comment: For performance considerations, `(lst1, lst2).zipped.map(f)` does the same but avoids creating the intermediary zipped list and the tuples.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in m-z's answer you can zip the lists, and then map on the list of tuples. If you want to avoid the use of `tupled`, you can do the destructure explicitly:

```
def map[A,B,C](f: (A, B) => C, lst1: List[A], lst2: List[B]): List[C] = {
  val zipped = lst1 zip lst2
  zipped.map { case (a,b) => f(a,b) }
}
```